# IC suggestions for WS28xx like functionality for driving transistors

Tags: microcontroller, led, serial, ws2812b, ws2811

I'm trying to light up string lights that run off of 12v taking up 500mA.
I'm using BC337 NPN transistor to turn individual string lights on/off where all of them are connected through a DC rail of 12v, injecting power at sufficient distances.

I want to make the strings individually controllable (per string) on/off or maybe dim too.
For this, I initially thought of using WS2811 and using the LED pins to drive the BJT transistor, but those are constant current open drain IC and hence cannot be used like this.

I need suggestions for alternative solution that can be implemented in the subcircuit area to achieve this serial transmission of led data, like using shift registers or something .

I have almost 160 of these so looking for some cost effective and easy to implement solutions.

[image: design of implementation]

Comment: Use the WS28XX as shown in your schematic, but add pullup resistors to provide the base current and invert the pixel data.

Comment: @Jens I couldn't get a chance to test your method, but I beleive yours works too. I have found a solution by directly using PNP transistor.

Comment: PNP is even better there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Substituting the NPN for a PNP transistor works by connecting Base to Input Drain of WS2811 and Collector to ground and using the Load on the emitter side.

Comment: Double check that base current, 18mA is quite a bit for a small transistor.  Glad you got it working.

Comment: I tested out with BC560 PNP transistor with hFe of 100, worked perfectly till 5 volts. Accidentally burnt a resistor on WS2811, I thought it was 12v tolerant on the power pins, turns out not. For my higher current use case, I'm thinking of using BC327 which can handle upto 800mA . Tested out on a circuit simulator and turns out I'd have to provide a 5v power rail aswell for the WS2811 in addition to 12v rail for the LED strings.

Answer (score 0):

The WS2811 outputs PWM on a pin for R,G and B each.  So if you had that PWM drive a transistor, then you can control a string of LEDs.  Something like the below should work.  If you aren't married to those BC337.

Also, as pointed out in the comments, you'd need to invert the data input value to make a high brightness be a high value number.  Or just write your code to use a low number for higher brightness.

Another, pointed out in the comments, the outputs are constant current and then PWMed for brightness.  So, understanding that, the idea below works (FETs are not a good idea anymore), we just need to add a current divider at each base.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fiZ7zq.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: As shown that won't work as the polarity is incorrect. The WS8211 output goes low to illuminate the LED. You could do similar using a PNP driver transistor with the LEDs connected between ground and the transistor.

Comment: @KevinWhite Simply invert the digital input value to the opposite.

Comment: @Aaron I can use a different transistor for sure. 
But as stated in question, the WS2811 IC's RGB pins operate in Constant Current drain mode. That means it operated on the low side with variable voltage that does not work with a N channel transistor. I tried with one which didn't work.
Inverting RGB brightness values is possible for my case.

Comment: As @KevinWhite said, I can try with a P channel one and update you.

Comment: @amankrokx Fun time working with those types of datasheet.  Half the time they say it's a PWM and the other they say current controlled output.  Those are not the same thing, at all.  If it is a current sink, then neither my solution nor Kevin's will work.  If it's a high frequency PWM, then both would work.

Comment: @Aaron The WS2811s I'm working with have a common anode RGB LED attached to it. The board has a physical trace connecting power line to the LED's common cathode and the rest to the RGB pins which when connected to the NPN transistor doesn't work. This means the one I'm using has current controlled sink.

Comment: If both solutions doesn't work , is there any other way ? I was thinking of using Latches or Shift registers as those are similarly priced and can atleast give me ON/OFF functionality than the WS chips that I had at hand.

Comment: @amankrokx Do you know how to code? You could easily make this with a simple microcontroller for each node, to replace the Ws2811

Comment: @Aaron Yes, I do code. The problem is, using 1 microcontroller per node become inefficient because the cost of microcontroller gets higher than the string lights itself 

Comment: @Aaron The LED drives are PWM’d constant-current outputs. Well, constant when they are ‘on’ anyway.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany aha! light bulb!

Comment: @amankrokx updated answer with input from SpehroPefhany

Comment: @Aaron Substituting NPN for a bjt PNP transistor worked. Connected the base to the input drain of WS2811 and Collector to ground worked directly.